# Azure IoT edge device hosting node-red module stopped working: error no space on device

Tags: docker, debian, node-red, azure-iot-edge, bullseye

I installed Azure IoT edge runtime on a Raspberry Pi 3 (Debian bullseye) to run my edge models. Everything worked well until I had an error:

```
A module runtime error occurred
        caused by: A module runtime error occurred
        caused by: connection error: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
        caused by: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
```

Thus I decided to run `sudo iotedge check` which gave the following:

```
Configuration checks (aziot-identity-service)
---------------------------------------------
√ keyd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ certd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ tpmd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ identityd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ daemon configurations up-to-date with config.toml - OK
√ identityd config toml file specifies a valid hostname - OK
√ aziot-identity-service package is up-to-date - OK
√ host time is close to reference time - OK
√ preloaded certificates are valid - OK
√ keyd is running - OK
√ certd is running - OK
√ identityd is running - OK
√ read all preloaded certificates from the Certificates Service - OK
√ read all preloaded key pairs from the Keys Service - OK
√ check all EST server URLs utilize HTTPS - OK
√ ensure all preloaded certificates match preloaded private keys with the same ID - OK

Connectivity checks (aziot-identity-service)
--------------------------------------------
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub AMQP port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub MQTT port - OK

Configuration checks
--------------------
√ aziot-edged configuration is well-formed - OK
√ configuration up-to-date with config.toml - OK
√ container engine is installed and functional - OK
× configuration has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - Error
    docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/90aaeea51acd3c6e7d8281710a36b5b9ceddff484170687e9364688d06956d6a-init: no space left on device.
    See 'docker run --help'.
√ aziot-edge package is up-to-date - OK
× container time is close to host time - Error
    Could not query local time inside container
√ DNS server - OK
‼ production readiness: logs policy - Warning
    Container engine is not configured to rotate module logs which may cause it run out of disk space.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-logs for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting log policy per module in the Edge deployment.
‼ production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
‼ production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeHub module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeHub directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
√ Agent image is valid and can be pulled from upstream - OK
√ proxy settings are consistent in aziot-edged, aziot-identityd, moby daemon and config.toml - OK

Connectivity checks
-------------------
× container on the default network can connect to upstream AMQP port - Error
    Container on the default network could not connect to dc-hub-rnd.azure-devices.net:5671
× container on the default network can connect to upstream HTTPS / WebSockets port - Error
    Container on the default network could not connect to dc-hub-rnd.azure-devices.net:443
× container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream AMQP port - Error
    Container on the azure-iot-edge network could not connect to dc-hub-rnd.azure-devices.net:5671
× container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream HTTPS / WebSockets port - Error
    Container on the azure-iot-edge network could not connect to dc-hub-rnd.azure-devices.net:443
26 check(s) succeeded.
3 check(s) raised warnings. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
6 check(s) raised errors. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
2 check(s) were skipped due to errors from other checks. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
```

I see that there is a problem with docker. Why this error occurs?
More about my edge modules running in a docker container: I use node-red module to connect to PLC via Ethernet and collect data from there for the delivery to IoT hub. I also make some message processing in the node-red module. Everything worked fine and by some reason this error appeared. I use several such IoT edge devices and want to be sure that such error won't happen again. Anyone has a guess on the root cause?

I also wonder how I can resolve this problem.

**UPDATE:**
Further investigations revealed that the disk space was full according to `df -h`.
I tried to free up the space using the first popping up googled methods, though it didn't help me out.
Other similar devices with the same modules take 10%-ish of the space.
I **assume** maybe node-red module logs flooded out the disk space because sometimes I was facing such messages as 'the logs are too big' and thus it was not showing me any. There might be some autotuning of cashed memory of node-red, might not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all of these errors have the exact root cause: your device is out of disk space. Can you verify if this is the case?

```
× configuration has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - Error
    docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/90aaeea51acd3c6e7d8281710a36b5b9ceddff484170687e9364688d06956d6a-init: no space left on device.
    See 'docker run --help'.
```

After you've cleaned up some space, be sure to check out the production checklist for Azure IoT Edge. It configures [image garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-1.4#configure-image-garbage-collection) and setting up [default logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-1.4#set-up-default-logging-driver) that includes log-rotation.

Comment: oh yeas, I struggled through from I posted the question. `df -h` shows me that my space is full, but I do not understand why, other similar devices are taking only 10% of the space. Do you know how to free up the space because I could not do it using first-googled methods?

Comment: It's very possible that you have a lot of unused docker images sitting around that can be deleted. Or perhaps there are too many log files being created.

Comment: Try a `docker image prune -a`
Either way, after cleaning up the disk, you will need to take steps to ensure it doesn't happen again. Look into log rotation for instance.

Comment: Thank, the problem was in logs. So now I am trying to understand how to delete or compress them. I saw .gz files can be deleted, right?

Comment: Great, I updated my answer with two items from the Production Checklist, they should help avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: I found out the following files become extremely large: `syslog.1`, `messages.1`, `user.log.1`. Do your suggestions limit the size of these files?